# Adding Framework in App Modules in iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I am working on a project where I have added Firebase, Crashlytics etc using POD.

Now there is a requirement to create modules for each feature available in the app, so I created Modules for each Feature (Say Profile, Payment, Linking etc) & its working fine with main container app.  Now My App looks like as below

[image]

Now I want to a use Framework(say Firebase) added Via POD in my module(Say Profile) but when I tried to import in a module I am getting

> No such module 'Firebase'

[image]

Please suggest me how can add Framework added Via POD in any module.

Please also let me know If I have explained my question.

Below is my POD file

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

use_frameworks!

def mainPodPackage
    pod 'Mapbox-iOS-SDK'
    pod 'ZendeskSDK'
    pod 'OneSignal'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
    pod 'FacebookSDK' 
end


target 'Production' do
    mainPodPackage
end

target 'PreProd' do
    mainPodPackage
end

target 'Dev' do
    mainPodPackage
end
```

Comment: Show your podfile please, you might need to install pod for those target you wanted to add also

Comment: I tried to install POD for added target but getting error 'Unable to find a target named '. Moreover I have added modules not a new target.

Comment: @Tj3n I have added code for POD file. Please have look

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can install pod for multiple project workspace, edit your podfile as so, test target should have same `project` as it's target:

```
use_frameworks!

workspace 'Workspace_name'
project 'PjA.xcodeproj'
project 'path_to_PjB/PjB.xcodeproj'

target 'PjA' do
    project 'PjA.xcodeproj'
    ...
end

target 'PjB' do
    project 'path_to_PjB/PjB.xcodeproj'
    ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I have added POS file in my question.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS Update your podfile format like this then it should work, I cant tell where you put the podfile and the projects so you have to update yourself

Comment: thanks for valuable input. I have edited my pod file and now I am able to debug. Saved my Day :) Thanks a lot